# Compare revenue: Windows 8 vs Windows Phone 7 vs Windows Phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone

There are application on phonegap for iOS and Android, which used SQLite 
Now I want move it to Windows, but there are problem - SQLite

As I understood, WP 7 & 8 supports SQLite, but W8 - no
I could not find data about market share for different Windows versions, in order to decide do I need wasting time for W8?
Also about WP7 vs 8, don't see any data about comparing revenue from these systems, I order to know on which i need concentrate

So I will very grateful for some statistics, links, suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest building for windows phone 7.8, which is also compatible with windows phone 8 devices.

As windows phone 8 app and windows 8 apps are not compatible, you will need to keep separate Views (in an MVVM architecture). I would suggest focusing on Windows Phone Apps, before implementing the Windows 8 version.

Look around you, how many of your friends have Windows Surface devices?
My experiences is that the Windows Phone market is emergent, and very few good apps are currently available, to its very easy to get noticed with a good app! On Android and IOS there are way to many apps available to get noticed.

Also on Windows Phone: Many users are quite annoyed, that the store has few apps, and most of the apps are hardly ever updated. I the periods when I update my apps often (My apps are: "Zen Mindfulness" and "Zen Of The Day"), I get very good reviews and high download counts! So its easy to make your app stand out from the croud in Windows Phone Store!

I also added a "Please rate" button in my apps, which resulted in an explosion in the number of good ratings, as I now also get rated by those who like and use my apps on a daily basis, and not just get rated by those few who doesn't like it, or doesn't understand what it is used for!

Hope this helps you on your way. Good luck!